# Put restrictions to OWL Imports

Tags: import, rdf, owl

I would like to know if it is possible to put some restrictions on owl:imports.

For example : I want to import foaf, because I want to use the semantics of foaf:Person and foaf:Organization. But I do not share the semantics of foaf:Image (I want the semantics of "Image" to be defined in my namespace).

So, I do not want foaf:Image and it's relations to be imported in my ontology. Is this possible to put restrictions, so that foaf:Image won't appear in my model... ?

I understand this might be contradictory with the "open world" assumption... and/or maybe I do not fully understand the "imports" mecanism.

Thank you by advance.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this with `owl:imports` but it's not a question of open world versus closed world. It is purely based on how `owl:imports` is supposed to work. Basically, what `owl:imports` says is "take whatever ontology terms and axioms you find at this URL and do as if they were part of my ontology". That would work in a closed world semantics too.

There's theoretical and experimental research on frameworks or formalisms that allow partial imports, but nothing really robust and maintained, when implemented at all. It's a known issue of the Web Ontology Language.

What you can do if you want to adhere to parts of the FOAF ontology is to simply copy the term declarations and axioms that you agree with in your ontology. For instance:

```
   ex:myOnto  a  owl:Ontology .
   foaf:Agent  a  owl:Class;
       rdfs:isDefinedBy  foaf: .
   foaf:Person  a  owl:Class;
       rdfs:subClassOf  foaf:Agent;
       rdfs:isDefinedBy  foaf: .
   foaf:Organization  a  owl:Class;
       rdfs:subClassOf  foaf:Agent;
       rdfs:isDefinedBy  foaf: .
```

Note that the `rdfs:isDefinedBy` is not really useful in terms of semantics but acknowledge the fact that these were borrowed from another ontology. Some people may consider that this is a bad practice, in the sense that you are defining terms that you do not have authority on (in the sense that you do not own the namespaces where a description of them can be retrieved) but that's the best I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

The import directives do not have this sort of granularity I'm afraid.